# Eclipse Spring Boot Build Path Contains Duplicate Entry

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I have been using Eclipse Luna and sprint boot for quite a while.  Just today, when I created a new project I am getting the following build error,

```
Build path contains duplicate entry: 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8' for project 'TomcatHttpDemo'
```

I am not sure if this is related to this problem but I tried

```
properties> Java Build Path > Libraries
```

and found that 'JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.8] was listed twice.  I deleted one of them and then cleaned and re-built the project.  I got a bunch of new errors.  These errors were all related to deleting the JRE system library.  I even restarted Eclipse several times to clear out any lingering errors.

I was running Luna 4.4 and upgraded to Mars 4.5 but the problem continues to persist.  I can build my old projects with no problems at all.  Using Luna or Mars the old projects build and execute properly.  Any time I try to create a new project I get the duplicate entry error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts) for Spring and Spring Boot Apps. It is an Eclipse-based IDE customized for developing Spring applications. It provides a ready-to-use environment to implement, debug, run, and deploy your Spring applications, including integrations for Pivotal tc Server, Pivotal Cloud Foundry, Git, Maven, AspectJ, and comes on top of the latest Eclipse releases.

Comment: Hello Sanjay, I already had STS 3.7.3 installed.  I checked for updates and re-ran the new project build.  Again, it failed with "Build path contains duplicate entry....JavaSE-1.8...  Not sure where to go from here.  Everything was working fine now I cannot create a new project.  I guess I will try and re-install the Java1.8 JDK and JDE.  Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Ok, tried some different combinations.  I can build a new spring boot project when I select "Maven" from the "New Spring Starter Project" window.  Looks like it might be a gradle problem.  Any idea's where I can start looking?

Comment: If the problem is with the Gardle project only then I guess you are missing Gradle Plugin for Eclipse/STS or something is wrong with it. Try installing/updating gradle plugin and check its settings. I never used gradle, so I'm not sure what where to start looking, but still give it a try.

Comment: I uninstalled/installed gradle with no luck.  The answer Kamel suggested below corrects the problem.  However, I now have to go and fix the class path issue every time I create a new project.  I did not have to do that before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if i understand your problem it's library issue with your project so

1.Select your project then go to Properties

2.Java build Path

3.in the Top select Libraires

4.add a JRE System Library

5.check the Execution Environment  Then Click to Environments

6.On the left click to Installed JREs

7.Then Click To add , Standard VM

8.click To directory Then go to /yourprograms/java/jdk 1.8

9.then Click finish after this check what you just added and click ok

10.when everything is closed update your maven Project

i hope it helps you

Comment: Ok, we are getting real close here.  I did as you recommended and it worked.   I tried a couple of combinations, specifically I removed the 2 "JRE System Libary [JavaSE-1.8]" in the library, selected Add Library, selected JRE System Library.  I noticed that the workspace default which was already selected pointed to the correct jre.  I just clicked finish, apply, and ok.  The project built correctly with no more build path errors.  Is there some default setting that is incorrectly building the project?  Like I said is there some problem with the gradle build?   It builds correctly in maven.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment.  The solution suggested by Kamel fixes the duplicate entries problem.  However, I now have to go in and fix the classplath problem whenever I now build a new project.  Is something that I can fix that eliminates the duplicate entries so I don't have to fix it each time I create a new project?

Comment: Then configure the above for settings globally. Instead of doing this for a single project, make this configuration without selecting any project, I'm not in front of my pc but I remember this setting should be under preferences - java - build path.

Comment: i don't get it did you meant you need a solution for every new project ? did you try Creating another project after what i just suggested you to do

Comment: could you tell me what's you jre  workspace default  you after Step 7

Comment: The workspace default JRE is jdk1.8.0_51.  I tried some other things and find that if I click the execution environment and select JavaSE-1.8[jdk1.8.0_51] this works as well.  It shows up as JRE System Libary [JavaSE-1.8].  This entry is the same as my older projects.  And to answer you previous question...yes, have to now fix the duplicate path problem whenever I create a new project.  I did not have to do that a couple of days ago.  Now I have to do it everytime.

Comment: Just to make things clearer, when I build a new project I get the duplicate path problem.  When look at the java build path libraries I have 2 JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] in my list of jars and class folders on the build path.  I remove both of them and then use the procedure recommended by Kamel.  When finished adding a new JRE System Library I now only just one JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] and the project no longer has the duplicate path problem.  It appears that spring boot is adding 2 instead of 1 System Library and they both are incorrect.  Make sense?

Comment: you are using maven i think in your pom.xml you have 1 or 2 of these <java.version>1.8</java.version>

Comment: I am going to close out this problem and mark Kamel's answer as correct.   However, I am going to open a new problem focused on the 2 JRE System Library entries.  This is the root issue.  For some reason during a new project build process 2 JRE System Libraries entries are being created.  I can't tell if they are correct or not.  If I delete both and then add JavaSe-1.8[jdk1.8.0] Library all duplicate errors are gone and the project builds correctly.  Thanks for everyones help...

Comment: I am using Gradle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108714/discussion-between-kamel-mili-and-skmansfield).