# Eclipse Spring Boot Build Path Contains Duplicate Entry

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I'm having the exact same question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507516/eclipse-spring-boot-build-path-contains-duplicate-entry). 
unfortunately he didn't find the ultimate one time fix solution either.

I will get the build path contains duplicate entry error each time when creating new project or refresh dependencies with gradle (maven works fine but gradle not).

I have to manually remove the extra jre system lib each time after the build. I think this problem might be caused by gradle setup. since after I manually fix the problem, it will raise again if I refresh the gradle dependencies.

here is the default sts build.gradle templete.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

you can see from the .classpath file, there are 2 same classpathentry for jreSE-1.8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="C:/Users/leo.zhou/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.6.RELEASE/8b780842222e055a165198d9f8198d3ff0da7f05/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/leo.zhou/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.6.RELEASE/6a1bd13afbae1dcd7207dfd6f8fd94b549fa32e5/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry> .....
```

please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding following to buildscript's dependencies

```
classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

and

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

at the end of the build.gradle file.

Comment: thanks, I tried your suggestions. but nothing changes, problem sitll persist

Comment: try gradle clean refresh --dependencies

Comment: I just found that I didn't enable the dependency management. after enable it, problem is fixed. do you know why does this happend?

Comment: If answer helped you solve the problem then you must accept as answer.